# share firefox/thunderbird profiles between windows and ubuntu - profile is in use

Tags: windows, ubuntu, firefox, thunderbird, firefox-profile

I have a dual boot PC with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. I want to share my Firefox and Thunderbird profiles between the to OS. I have a "DATA" partition where the profiles are located.

I have set the profile location correcly and I successfully started the profiles but after the first use, i cant use it anymore. (it says the profile is already in use or the application is already running but not responding).

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you did not shutdown Firefox/Thunderbird correctly before switching the OS, so the profiles are locked now to prevent data loss by accidential modifications from different parallel processes.

You need to remove the lock files to be able to use the profiles again, see http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_in_use#Remove_the_profile_lock_file

> ## Remove the profile lock file
>
> The application may have shut down abnormally, leaving the lock in place. To fix this, open the profile folder and delete the file,
>
> - "parent.lock" (Windows),
> - "lock" and ".parentlock" (Linux)

You might also want to read http://kb.mozillazine.org/Sharing_a_profile_between_Windows_and_Linux to get some hints on running such an setup you are trying to achieve.